# Visual Studio unknown debug icon

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I was debugging C# in Visual Studio 2017, and debugger stopped on an exception. Some static members can't initialize, and exception is raised in member's class constructor. In Auto window I saw this icon that I have never seen before:

[image]

Blue box stands for class member. What does squared number one stand for?

I went through the [Visual Studio Image Library 2017](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35825), a pdf file within a zip file, but couldn't find this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means "static member field". The "1" apparently means "has only one instance".